# eclipse - org.eclipse.epp.usagedata.recording is thrown though usage collector is disabled

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-indigo

I just faced a strange exception in Eclipse Indigo; Each start Eclipse throws some IO exception... here is the log file which was generated right after Eclipse started :

```
!SESSION 2014-12-27 23:40:06.656 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=M20120208-0800
java.version=1.7.0_71
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=linux, ARCH=x86_64, WS=gtk, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product
Command-line arguments:  -os linux -ws gtk -arch x86_64 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product

!ENTRY org.eclipse.epp.usagedata.recording 4 0 2014-12-27 23:41:27.685
!MESSAGE Error writing events to file.
!STACK 0
java.io.FileNotFoundException: .../.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.epp.usagedata.recording/usagedata.csv (Permission denied)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:221)
    at java.io.FileWriter.<init>(FileWriter.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.epp.usagedata.internal.recording.UsageDataRecorder.createEventWriter(UsageDataRecorder.java:174)
    at org.eclipse.epp.usagedata.internal.recording.UsageDataRecorder.getWriter(UsageDataRecorder.java:169)
    at org.eclipse.epp.usagedata.internal.recording.UsageDataRecorder.dumpEvents(UsageDataRecorder.java:145)
    at org.eclipse.epp.usagedata.internal.recording.UsageDataRecorder.stop(UsageDataRecorder.java:77)
    at org.eclipse.epp.usagedata.internal.recording.UsageDataRecordingActivator.stop(UsageDataRecordingActivator.java:75)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl$2.run(BundleContextImpl.java:771)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.stop(BundleContextImpl.java:764)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.stopWorker(BundleHost.java:510)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.suspend(AbstractBundle.java:565)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework.suspendBundle(Framework.java:1161)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.decFWSL(StartLevelManager.java:595)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.doSetStartLevel(StartLevelManager.java:257)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.shutdown(StartLevelManager.java:215)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.InternalSystemBundle.suspend(InternalSystemBundle.java:284)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework.shutdown(Framework.java:691)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework.close(Framework.java:598)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.shutdown(EclipseStarter.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:198)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:622)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:577)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1410)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1386)
```

The Usage Data Collector is disabled. So my question is how to fix that? BTW currently I am suffering windowbuilder freeze each swing component adding so may the mentioned exception cause that?

p.s. Eclipse Indigo J2SE Linux x64

Thanks

Comment: plz try to run eclipse as administrator

Comment: In admin mode I get terminal output as : "isRtl: false" and "Error parsing gtk-icon-sizes string: ''" ?

Comment: sorry i have no idea

Comment: I just want to ask is there a way really to make eclipse not read the usagedata.csv file on each ide start? I have Data Usage Collector disabled but why reading is taking place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open 'Window > Preferences > General > Startup and Shutdown'. Deselect the two 'Usage Data Collector' entries and click OK. This should completely disable the usage data collection (you might need to restart Eclipse).

Later releases of Eclipse no longer include usage data collection.

More information [here](https://wiki.eclipse.org/UDC)